# How can I get a route from 2 coords in React JS (and its distance)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps, distance

First at all, I have to say Im a newbie with React and I am developing a project based on maps api for academic purposes.

The problem is that I have 2 coords got from two differents Autocomplete inputs and then, I need to trace a route in the map and to get the distance of it.

This is my code (polyline doesnt works):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";

import { Polyline } from "react-google-maps";

import Marker from "./../Marker/Marker";

class SimpleMap extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      center: {
        lat: 40.3925046,
        lng: -3.700465,
      },
      zoom: 14,
    };
  }

  render() {
    //const pathCoordinates = [this.props.coordenates.origin, this.props.coordenates.destination]

    return (
      <div style={{ height: "50vh", width: "100%" }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{
            key: "myKey",
          }}
          center={
            this.props.coordenates.origin.lat
              ? this.props.coordenates.origin
              : this.state.center
          }
          defaultZoom={this.state.zoom}
        >
          {this.props.coordenates.origin.lat ? (
            <Marker
              lat={this.props.coordenates.origin.lat}
              lng={this.props.coordenates.origin.lng}
              text="My Marker"
            />
          ) : null}

          {this.props.coordenates.destination.lat ? (
            <Marker
              lat={this.props.coordenates.destination.lat}
              lng={this.props.coordenates.destination.lng}
              text="My Marker"
            />
          ) : null}
          <Polyline
            path={[
              { lat: -36.73540441, lng: 144.25178598 },
              { lat: -36.73590441, lng: 134.25178198 },
            ]} //{[this.props.coordenates.origin, this.props.coordenates.destination]} //{pathCoordinates}
            options={{
              strokeColor: "#00ffff",
              strokeOpacity: 0.7,
              strokeWeight: 1,
            }}
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SimpleMap;
```

Thank you so much!